# How to generate a random reducible flow graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Is there any known algorithm to generate a random [**reducible** flow graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88109/what-is-a-reducible-flow-graph?newreg=8d0cb40b4ed04ea1933e1f72a4b2143a) (single root, single sink) with a given maximum cardinality $N$?

Ideally, the distribution should be uniform over the set of reducible flow graphs of cardinality $\leq N$.
Alternatively, it could be uniform over the possible topologies of reducible flow graphs of cardinality $\leq N$ (e.g. graphs that are isomorphic or that differ just for the length of some chain can be considered equivalent).
The *exact* distribution is not dictated by my use case (random testing), so I would also be interested in other non-uniform distributions that assign a non-zero probability to any possible topology.

Two approaches that I found so far are:

1. Randomly generate a flow graph (same considerations as before regarding the distribution), test if it is reducible, repeat until it is reducible.
2. Construct a graph from a grammar, for example the one described in Sec. 7 of ["Flow Graph Reducibility"](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=804919), randomly choosing the rule to apply and recursively applying the algorithm to generate the sub-graphs.

I'm pretty sure that the time complexity of (1) would be too high to be used in practice (let say, $N=1000$). (2) is feasible, but it lacks forward edges that exit from a loop, which are crucial in my use case. It would be possible to define another grammar, but then the question is whether the new grammar can actually generate any graph topology.